# How to find cause of transaction log filling up

Tags: sql-server-2008

Have a process that loads some data to a specific db.  Works fine until a particular day and fails because the tlog is full.  There is nothing different about that day for the process Im running.  If the transaction log fills up **before** the next iteration of the log backup, then how can I find out the likely cause of this?  Possibly search various DMV's looking for insert/update/delete statements?  I suspect there is another job (or jobs) running that is doing a log of "small" updates on a frequent basis to this same db, but on one day in particular something has enough transaction volume to fill the tlog before the backup can run.

Rather than simply increase the log size or take more frequent backups, I want to know WHY and WHAT is doing this activity just prior to the log filling up.  Any suggestions?  If I monitored the tlog size and then after the next instance of this, compared the query history that included dml statements, would that give me a picture of what was writing to the db just prior to the tlog filling up?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/73923/95107 and, linked from Aaron's answer, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space

Comment: thank you, I think Im going to try this. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic540603-5-1.aspx  - basically, I want to look for anything that does a write (DML) and involves the database Im interested in.